# How can I get a list of all categories in GetEventStore?

Tags: eventstoredb

From streams like these:

- sales-sale102
- sales-sale103
- sales-sale104
- users-8989
- users-8990

Get somethig like this:

```
[ "sales", "users"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [nissbran from GitHub](https://github.com/EventStore/EventStore/issues/1445)

```
fromStream('$streams')
.when({
$init: function () {
    return []
},
$any: function (s, e) {
    var category = e.streamId.split("-")[0];

    if (s.includes(category))
        return;

    s.push(category);
}
})
```